# Get last bytes from byte array

Tags: c#, reverse

I need to read last 8 bytes from byte array. Right now im doing it like this:

```
last8 = data.Reverse().Take(8).Reverse();
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Either that or you can use `Array.Copy`

Comment: The Copy is probably the best way to use, because a Reverse operation can be quite costly depending on the size; especially if data is big.

Comment: What do you mean better? faster? More readable?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, `Reverse().Take(m)` operation is O(m) when applied to an arbitrary-length **array**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) for example:

```
byte[] data = ...;
byte[] last8 = new byte[8];
Array.Copy(data, data.Length-8, last8, 0, 8);
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
var last8 = data.Skip(data.Length - 8);
```

Would save the step of reversing an array twice.

Comment: Skip might need to go over (almost) the entire array until it reaches the desired index. If penartur's comment is correct, Reverse().Take(8) should only go over 8 items. Since the 8 is constant and the array size could be huge, the latter seems preferable.

Answer (score 2):

C# 8 has [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) that might help ...

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
byte[] last3 = bytes [^3..];  
// last3 contains { 3, 4, 5 }
```

examples...

```
           START      END          EXAMPLE         ALSO KNOWN AS
[^3..]  - 3rd back  - end         { 3, 4, 5 }        last 3
[3..]   - 3rd       - end         { 4, 5 }           skip 3
[3..^2] - 3rd       - 3rd back    { }              
[..^3]  - beginning - 4rd back    { 1, 2 }           skip last 3
[..3]   - beginning - 4rd         { 1, 2, 3 }        first 3
[..]    - beginning - end         { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }  all
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.Skip(data.Count - 8)` (if your data is already enumerated - e.g. an `Array` or `List`).